# 'AnyHashable' is not convertible to

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am converting my project Objective-C code to Swift. The thing fine but while having its for in loop i am facing error something like its type conversion issue. Thanks In Advance.

```
class GymUserSession: NSObject {

var passes = [AnyHashable]()

func getPassList() -> [AnyHashable]? {
        var list = [AnyHashable]()
        for pass: GymPass? in passes {
            if pass?.isGift == nil || pass?.activated != nil {
                if let aPass = pass {
                    list.append(aPass)
                }
            }
        }
        return list
    }
}
```

GymPass is another NSObject Class

```
class GymPass: NSObject {
var gymID : String
var passID : String
var isGift : Bool
var activated : Bool
var dateCreated : Date?
var dateActivated : Date?
}
```

[image: Error screen]

Comment: Have you just put Objective-C through some sort of Swift converter? The `GymPass` object doesn't have `isGift` and `activated` properties. Your fundamental problem is due to the use of `AnyHashable` instead of the specific `GymPass`. I don't want to be unkind but this code is fairly awful, which is why I suspect it is some sort of automatic translation.

Comment: @Paulw11 updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that Swift can't implicitly downcast an `AnyHashable` to a `GymPass`, which is what you have asked it to do.

You *could* fix the error by explicitly downcasting, but really that is just addressing one small issue that would let the code compile

In Swift you should always use the most explicit type you can, when it is known.  Types such as `Any`, `AnyObject` and `AnyHashable` should only be used when you don't know the type or there may be multiple types.  For example a dictionary obtained decoding JSON could be `[String:Any]` since you know it will have `String` keys, but the value types will be varied.

In this case, presumably, you know that `passes` will contain `GymPass` instances. A more "Swifty" version of your code could look something like this (but it is hard to be specific as I don't have enough detail on where the data is coming from and what you are trying to achieve, exactly):

```
struct GymPass {
    var gymID: String
    var passID: String
    var isGift: Bool
    var dateCreated: Date
    var dateActivated: Date?
    var isActivated: Bool {
        get {
            return self.dateActivated != nil
        }
    }
}

class GymUserSession: NSObject {

    var passes = [GymPass]()

    func getPassList() -> [GymPass] {

        return passes.filter ( { $0.isGift || $0.isActivated } )

    }
}
```